# teleop_base deprecated, need generic teleop package

Tags: ros, teleop-base, teleoperation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

It looks like [teleop_base](http://ros.org/wiki/teleop_base) is deprecated according to [its manifest](https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/branches/trunk_cturtle/sandbox/teleop_base/manifest.xml).

So my question is this: is pr2_teleop the new "generic" teleop package? If so, why the "pr2" prefix? I have a bunch of heterogeneous robots, whats the best "universal" teleop package? I need joystick and keyboard support at a minimum.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9207/teleop_base-deprecated,-need-generic-teleop-package/) by [JeffRousseau](https://answers.ros.org/users/75/jeffrousseau/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1607 on 2011-02-25

Post score: 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is now a github organization for generic teleop tools in ros: https://github.com/ros-teleop

For teleop using a keyboard, there is [teleop_twist_keyboard](http://wiki.ros.org/teleop_twist_keyboard)

For teleop using a joystick there is a new package in ROS Indigo called [teleop_twist_joy](http://wiki.ros.org/teleop_twist_joy)

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So as far as I know, there's no real official, universal teleop package currently for robots.

My current advice is to just write your own nodes that take an input from a joystick and will output a [/cmd_vel Twist](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/Twist.html).  See http://www.ros.org/wiki/joystick_drivers.  This makes an especially useful challenge for people new to ROS, as it requires using a provided driver for their XBOX/PS3/Wiimote and then interfacing that to their robot through their own small, easy segment of code.

The same could easily be done for keyboard input.

I'd recommend looking at [our teleop node](http://https://github.com/cwru-robotics/cwru-ros-pkg/blob/master/cwru_semi_stable/cwru_teleop/src/teleop_cwru_joy.cpp) that takes in an XBOX 360 controller as /joy and outputs a twist if you need to see how someone else did it.

For keyboard related teleop, the hardest part would be capturing the key presses.  You might find something useful in the [old teleop_base code](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/teleop_base/html/teleop__base__keyboard_8cpp_source.html).  The segment for capturing key-presses should still be valid, just be sure the dependencies are all still good or that you can find useful versions of them.  You may also want to check out the [brown-ros-pkg teleop_twist_keyboard](http://www.ros.org/wiki/teleop_twist_keyboard) code to see if there are useful hints there.

My guess is that joysticks vary too much in number and order of axes that no one would find a more universal driver that useful.  It would seem that we would end up with XBOX->Twist, PS3->Twist, and WiiMoteNunchuk->Twist, so it's probably better to quickly whip up your own.

---

Originally posted by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) with karma: 4541 on 2011-03-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey Jeff,

In my experience, you should use the code shown in the turotial [Writing a Teleoperation Node for a Linux-Supported Joystick](http://www.ros.org/wiki/joy/Tutorials/WritingTeleopNode).

It creates a very handy joystick teleop system.
You can easily associate one axis with one velocity command type and set its output range directly from the launch file:

```
<launch>
...
 <!-- Axes -->
  <param name="axis_linear" value="1" type="int"/>
  <param name="axis_angular" value="0" type="int"/>
  <param name="scale_linear" value="2" type="double"/>
  <param name="scale_angular" value="2" type="double"/>

  <node pkg="turtle_teleop" type="turtle_teleop_joy" name="teleop"/>

</launch>
```

Still, as Chad said, you need to make the node output a cmd_vel twist message.

Raph

---

Originally posted by [raphael favier](https://answers.ros.org/users/139/raphael-favier/) with karma: 1382 on 2011-03-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We provide a fairly generic Joy->Twist node in this package, which you're welcome to use: [clearpath_teleop](http://www.ros.org/wiki/clearpath_teleop)

There's no keyboard component at this point, though you'd be welcome to contribute one. Also, it's rospy, which may be problematic depending on your environment and needs.

---

Originally posted by [mikepurvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/270/mikepurvis/) with karma: 1153 on 2011-03-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there!

We recently used the teleop_base package to move our robot (in Gazebo) with our Logitech RumblePad 2 controller.

We ran into a major bug, which made the node crash. My question now is, should I file a ticket although the package is deprecated?

The effort for fixing the bug would be small. I think this package is still useful, since people with a similar controller to the PS3/Logitech RumblePad can easily set up a teleop pipeline without doing any/a lot of coding.

:-) Marcus

PS: for fixing the bug we changed

```
00193 
00194   ros::Rate pub_rate(20);
00195 
00196   TeleopBase teleop_base(no_publish);
00197   teleop_base.init();
00198
```

to

```
00193 
00194   TeleopBase teleop_base(no_publish);
00195   teleop_base.init();
00196   
00197   ros::Rate pub_rate(20); 
00198
```

---

Originally posted by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) with karma: 2062 on 2011-04-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I've recently announced a teleop stack which allows generic tele-operation "source" devices (such as keyboards, joysticks, etc.) to be used interchangeably to control generic tele-operation "sink" devices (such as robot bases, pan-tilt units, robot arms, etc.).

The code can be downloaded here:
https://github.com/skynetish/generic_teleop

More information can be found here:
https://github.com/skynetish/generic_teleop/wiki

Comments and feedback welcome!

Best,
Kevin

---

Originally posted by [leblanc_kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1052/leblanc_kevin/) with karma: 357 on 2012-02-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on 2012-03-08**:
These links gives 404 error

**Comment by [leblanc_kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1052/leblanc_kevin/) on 2012-03-08**:
Thanks for letting me know, I've updated the links (I announced the changed links to the mailing list, but forgot to update this post).  Between the time I started and announced my "teleop" stack someone else created a package named "teleop".  I've renamed my stack to "generic_teleop".

**Comment by [cognitiveRobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/6861/cognitiverobot/) on 2013-10-22**:
Hi Kevin,

I downloaded generic_teleop in my catkin_ws_hydro then i did rosmake generic_teleop. Is it proper way to install? How can i execute to teleop my robot my keyboard?

thanks

**Comment by [Quadrobo](https://answers.ros.org/users/8696/quadrobo/) on 2014-01-09**:
The generic_teleop is for master version. If you look at the contents of the generic_teleop, they utilise stack.xml instead of package.xml (which Hydro is based on). So I am guessing there is much to change before it can be used.

**Comment by [leblanc_kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1052/leblanc_kevin/) on 2014-04-20**:
Sorry for not responding sooner, for some reason I didn't get any notifications about your comments.  I haven't updated my stack to catkin yet.  I've changed jobs and as such I'm having trouble finding free time to work on this.  But I hope to get around to it soon-ish!

**Comment by [andrestoga](https://answers.ros.org/users/21535/andrestoga/) on 2015-03-28**:
Hi leblanc_kevin,

Did you update your stack to catkin?

Best,

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-03-28**:
I've removed this as an accepted answer because it's no longer being maintained.

**Comment by [leblanc_kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1052/leblanc_kevin/) on 2016-03-10**:
Sorry for not being in touch earlier, I accidentally turned off notifications from ROS answers.  I've been out of the robotics branch for a while now.  I keep hoping I'll have time to stay at it in my spare time, but it's proving to be more difficult than I thought.  I'll shout if anything changes!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For Hydro, this one seemed cool !
http://wiki.ros.org/teleop_twist_keyboard

---

Originally posted by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) with karma: 1108 on 2014-06-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1